# How to draw a circle and then when keyPressed, draw another circle etc

Tags: processing

I am learning how to code in Processing 4.

I am trying to make a code where when `keyPressed()` is clicked, one circle is drawn then when the button is pressed again, the first circle remains and then a second circle is drawn but with extent increased by 10, then the key pressed for a final time (3) and the third circle is drawn with the extent increased by 3 then it stops producing more circles.

This is the code I have so far but I am confused on how to approach it. Right now, the first circle just increases in size and it doesn't draw a second one. How do I draw 3 circles, one once `keyPressed()`?

```
int sizeIncrease = 10;
int initialSize = 70;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  stroke(255,0,0);
  strokeWeight(25);
  fill(255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(20, 50);
  circle(width/2, height/2, initialSize);
  popMatrix();
}

void keyPressed() {
  initialSize += sizeIncrease;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a variable `count`. Increment the variable when a key is pressed and draw the circles in a `for`-loop:

```java
int sizeIncrease = 10;
int initialSize = 70;
int count = 1;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(20, 50);
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    circle(width/2, height/2, initialSize + i*sizeIncrease);
  }
  popMatrix();
}

void keyPressed() {
  count ++;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) I had tried the same concept with arcs but it would not work. Would you be able to push me in the right direction? I am trying to mimic the same movement with the circles but with arcs - i added arc(0,0, initialSize, initialSize+i*sizeIncrease, 0, radians(360/6)); in the for loop with the circle but all the arcs overlap

Comment: @lunalilac The comment section is not intended ask follow-up questions. If you have a new question you need to [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Anyway you have to increase the width and height `arc(0,0, initialSize+i*sizeIncrease, initialSize+i*sizeIncrease, 0, radians(360/6));`

Answer (score 1):

```
int sizeIncrease = 10;
int initialSize = 70;
int count = 1;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);


  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(20, 50);
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
  {
      circle(width/2, height/2, initialSize + i*sizeIncrease);
      **if(i == 1)
      {
           sizeIncrease = 3;
      }**
  }
  popMatrix();
}

void keyPressed() {
  count ++;
}
```